# Dynamically loading modules in Python (+ multi processing question)

Tags: python

I am writing a Python package which reads the list of modules (along with ancillary data) from a configuration file.

I then want to iterate through each of the dynamically loaded modules and invoke a do_work() function in it which will spawn a new process, so that the code runs ASYNCHRONOUSLY in a separate process.

At the moment, I am importing the list of all known modules at the beginning of my main script - this is a nasty hack I feel, and is not very flexible, as well as being a maintenance pain.

This is the function that spawns the processes. I will like to modify it to dynamically load the module when it is encountered. The key in the dictionary is the name of the module containing the code:

```
def do_work(work_info):
  for (worker, dataset) in work_info.items():
    #import the module defined by variable worker here...

    # [Edit] NOT using threads anymore, want to spawn processes asynchronously here...

    #t = threading.Thread(target=worker.do_work, args=[dataset])
    # I'll NOT dameonize since spawned children need to clean up on shutdown
    # Since the threads will be holding resources
    #t.daemon = True
    #t.start()
```

**Question 1**

When I call the function in my script (as written above), I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no
>   attribute 'do_work'

Which makes sense, since the dictionary key is a string (name of the module to be imported).

When I add the statement:

**import worker**

before spawning the thread, I get the error:

> ImportError: No module named worker

This is strange, since the variable name rather than the value it holds are being used - when I print the variable, I get the value (as I expect) whats going on?

**Question 2**

As I mentioned in the comments section, I realize that the do_work() function written in the spawned children needs to cleanup after itself. My understanding is to write a clean_up function that is called when do_work() has completed successfully, or an unhandled exception is caught - is there anything more I need to do to ensure resources don't leak or leave the OS in an unstable state?

**Question 3**

If I comment out the t.daemon flag statement, will the code stil run ASYNCHRONOUSLY?. The work carried out by the spawned children are pretty intensive, and I don't want to have to be waiting for one child to finish before spawning another child.  BTW, I am aware that threading in Python is in reality, a kind of time sharing/slicing  - thats ok

Lastly is there a better (more Pythonic) way of doing what I'm trying to do?

**[Edit]**

After reading a little more about Pythons GIL and the threading (ahem - hack) in Python, I think its best to use separate processes instead (at least IIUC, the script can take advantage of multiple processes if they are available), so I will be spawning new processes instead of threads.

I have some sample code for spawning processes, but it is a bit trivial (using lambad functions). I would like to know how to expand it, so that it can deal with running functions in a loaded module (like I am doing above).

This is a snippet of what I have:

```
def do_mp_bench():
    q = mp.Queue() # Not only thread safe, but "process safe"
    p1 = mp.Process(target=lambda: q.put(sum(range(10000000))))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=lambda: q.put(sum(range(10000000)))) 
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    r1 = q.get()
    r2 = q.get()
    return r1 + r2
```

How may I modify this to process a dictionary of modules and run a do_work() function in each loaded module in a new process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was revised to make use of **import**() documentation here: [import](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) and refactored to utilize the requested multiprocessing module as documented here: [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html). This hasn't been tested.

```
def do_work(work_info):
    q = mp.Queue()
    for (worker, dataset) in work_info.items():
      xworker = __import__(worker)
      p = mp.Process(target=xworker.do_work, args=dataset).start()
      q.put(p)
    while not q.empty():
      r = q.get()
```

Comment: No need to use `exec` when you can just use `__import__()`.

Comment: had no idea about __import__(). I just thought about how I would do it with the limited knowledge I have on the subject. I will refactor the answer to take advantage of the new knowledge.

Comment: +1 for your effort. I had already done this by the time you posted your answer though. As my modified question states though, I want to spawn processes instead of threads now. Do you know how to modify your code to spawn a process ASYNCHRONOUSLY instead of a thread?

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: use [`__import__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__).

Question 2: why not just do the cleanup at the end of the `do_work()` function?

Question 3: IIRC daemon thread just means that the program won't automatically wait for this thread to end.

Comment: +1 for the __import__() function. Thats what I needed. Regarding cleanup, yes, I am thinking of doing that, just wanted to know if there was anything else to do. Regarding Q3, from what you are saying, commenting out the daemon flag WILL make the program run SYNCHRONOUSLY? (that is NOT what I want)

Comment: @morpheous: if you daemonize the thread, you have to use the `join()` method explicitly if you want to wait the end of the thread. At the end of your program, non-daemon threads will automatically be joined.
This is what you usually want. Threads are supposed to run in parallel in both cases, but because of the GIL they won't.

Comment: sorry for being 'slow on the take' here .. but I still dont understand exactly what you're saying. So I will restate my question (and actually change it slightly in the process). I want to run a child PROCESS (Note: not thread anymore - after reading out more about threading in Python), and then let it run asynchronously (i.e. do not wait for it to finish). Could you provide a link/snippet that shows how to do this?

Comment: @morpheous: look at the multiprocessing module. It works like the threading module, but spawns processes instead of threads.